# Accuracy of GPS Timestamp in depending on position accuracy

Tags: android, ios, gps

In need to exploit in my application time obtained from GPS. I need position and I need to know a time stamp which I can globally trust.

I'm getting information how accurate my position is, for instance 5m, 100m etc. 
But I would like to know how accurate it my timestamp depending on position accuracy. Of course I know that the accuracy of the position is correlated with accuracy of the timestamp (this is basic idea of gsp), but I would like know what error of the timestamp (in miliseconds) should I expect when I'm getting position with  accuracy 5m ,50m, 100m etc. Is there easy way to calculate that?

Comment: i don't understand what you want. if you ask about when the sample was taken, it's always available. it's part of the Location class : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime()

Comment: I want to know how precise is the timestamp, simplifying the problem for instance if I can set the device clock using that timestamp which I get together with my position.

Comment: it's as precise as it gets. getTime is in ms , while getElapsedRealtimeNanos  returns it in ns . of course, it could take some time till the event is received.

Comment: @androiddeveloper first question is how long it could takes until the event is received, It's a matter of ms or s ? Second issue is how accuracy of the position we have (in other words number of satellites we catch) influence on the current timestamp quality?  Where quality I understand as a diffrence from real atomic clock.

Comment: it depends on hardware and how much stress the device has. for example , if your app got a sample on time X , and from time X-1 to time X+1 you've used the UI thread, you will get the even only on time X+1 . not only that, but if you got events before the sampling, they will be fired first. that's why you need to use proper calculation and not use the time you got the even, but instead use the time that was set in the event's result. about accuracy of the position, it is set in the result, and this is also a hardware thing (together with software too, since they probably have an algorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time from gps is precise (micros or nanos) , but this does not help you because the smartphone can delay the location message up to one second.

Comment: So in simple words, if I'm getting gps timestamp I cannot use it for instance to set the phone clock to the actual time, because the message might be delayed?

Comment: It always depends on what you exactly want. Syncronizing timestamp of smartphone to GPS is better done by the operating system of the phone.